# How can i save a form without a submit button in django

Tags: python, django, forms

i have a doubt, i want to save a form and without use a submit button.

Because, as you´ll see:

[image]

i need to increase "cantidad" but i don't want to use a "sumbmit" button, otherwise, i need that the data (integers) will stay correctly in a database field.

Because, in my models.py i have:

```
cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to modify the field 'cantidad' when the user increase or decrease Selection, as you see in the image and without a submit button.

Is there a way to do this?

Any help thank you!.

Comment: you would send a request back to your server with the new  value every time the "cantidad" value was updated in the UI. in this case, it's probably in the `onChange` event handler

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript and ajax and send back the relevant data on every change

Comment: @wpercy could you show me an example?

Comment: it's entirely dependent on the structure of your code

Comment: @wpercy Yes but, how can i do a event handler onChange with django??

Comment: there plenty of questions on here asking that exact question, try doing some more research

Comment: Do you HAVE to save that field before buying??? Cause the way I'm seeing it, is you just want people to be able to select a quantity, THEN buy that quantity - no saving is required. Reply back and I'll answer, cause there's a couple ways to do this. The hard way is a [Javascript XMLHttpRequest](https://pwnsaucedesigns.com/blog/2019/4/14/javascript-xmlhttprequest-ajax-example-xhr-form-submit-no-jquery-get-post-open-send-responsetext-python-django-mvc-select-radio-button-json/). The example there on my blog shows how to do it with django, but again, there's an easier way depending on your needs.

Comment: @PwnSauceDesigns  Well, the think is i have a field in my dataBase called "cantidad", and it saves the quantity of the articles that the user will buy. So, i need to save the REAL quantity that the user want to buy, do you understand me? So, i thought that the better way to do it is save the value when the UI is updated and the user decrease or increase that button, this is the reason that i thought this... Anyways, if you have another method to do this, or a better way im totally open to any thing that you suggest me. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: So before a person buys, you want them to select the amount? And that is all?

Comment: @PwnSauceDesigns Yes exactly!. Oh! and i almost forgot. The fields "sub-total" and "precio total" of the tables from the image that i put in here, i want to refresh the values when the user increase or decrease the button. Maybe is more complicated, but firstly i wanted to do it, if actually i can´t do it, i won´t. So yeah, before a person buys i want to select the amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to you, something like this will work, but you'll have to modify it to your needs. [I would use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/) because their values are stored without having to save your current modelfield in the database, and users could still browse the site without having to update the values every time.

**Remember:** Sessions are accessible like dictionaries. But you have to .save() them just like you would any model, because it's still a model stored in the database. The reason you should use these instead of your product model is because sessions are intended to be random, and are easy to clear with `python manage.py clearsessions`. If you used your own model, assuming you have thousands of models to dig through which were never purchased by someone, this is FAR EASIER and faster, and keeps your database cleaner.

This is a quick answer, though I suggest you implement a shopping cart that's already been made by someone else. Check [djangopackages.org](https://djangopackages.org/) for some good ones. What they have will be better than what I'm about to show you, though this is the principle you follow either way.

**GENERAL STEPS TO TAKE:**

1. Make a session key: `request.session['cart'] = {}`
2. Add keys and values to it: `request.session['cart']['product_id'] = 111`
3. Add more values to that product: `request.session['cart']['quantity'] = 222`
4. Save it: `request.session.save()`

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, with the session the user will store their values, but i have to save it anyways because i am still working with my models. To finally save the values when i want. I have never used them, so i may ask.

Comment: Let's say you're a doctor. Before working, you put on a pair of disposable latex gloves. When you're done, you throw them away so your next patient doesn't get cross contaminated. Sessions are like that. With your models, you could save it by putting a link on the page that gets the `name=` attribute in your html, which gets the `value=` attribute of that, and then `obj.save()` it, ***but that's very inefficient.*** The reason why is because of the `clearsessions` comment I made.

Comment: Very nice answer and very well explained, thank you!